# material refresh click event not working

Tags: javascript, refresh, swipe

i use this plugin [material-refresh](https://github.com/lightningtgc/material-refresh) to refresh page it's working fine but when the page is scrolled at the top "TOP = 0" click wont fire and when i scroll it down by 1px it's work normally here an image enplane the problem better 
[image]

Here the test code

```js
  var opts_stream = {
        nav: '.page_header',
        scrollEl: '.page_content',
        onBegin: function() {
            console.log("start");
        },
        onEnd: function() {
            console.log("Done");
        }
    };
    mRefresh(opts_stream);
```

```css
       .page_header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .page_content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 1200px;
            background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>sdasd</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://github.com/lightningtgc/material-refresh/blob/master/src/css/material-refresh.styl">
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lightningtgc/material-refresh/master/src/js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page_header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="page_content">
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="alert('test');">Test Button</button>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

NOTE : You need to run browser in mobile mood from chrome console to get this plugin to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in line 304 in touchEnd function in material-refresh.js remove e.preventDefault();
 :)